# Java Axis 2 Script wont start without JAVA_HOME Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis, serversocket, wsdl2java

Hello guys this is the first time i write a question here and not just read an answer.

My problem is that I have a Macbook with Sierra on it and hava a tomcat with my wsdl file and i wanted to generate my classes with axis2 so i started the wsdl2java.sh in Eclipse and till that point everything works fine.
But then it says:

You must set the `JAVA_HOME` variable before running Axis2 Script.

but when i open a terminal and lookup for

`echo $JAVA_HOME` it will say:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and also when i type in `java -version i` get this result:

> java version "1.8.0_101" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_101-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

my question is why does eclipse not found my JAVA_HOME path?
i allready started eclipse as sudo directly through the terminal and also tried to change the .bash_profile but nothing works for me

I hope i described the Problem so that you can help me !
thanks a lot

Comment: So Eclipse is running the shell script, wsdl2java.sh? Try adding `export JAVA_HOME=...` in the first line of the script.

Comment: no i added it through the external tools to have it automatically run when i started it

Comment: Try add JAVA_HOME in that script to see if it make any different.

Comment: OH MY GOD ! THANKS A LOT IT WORKED sorry for caps but i just tried it for two days ! thanks a lot man !

Comment: No problems. I am happy to be useful :) If you post your answer to complete your question...I am happy to give you some votes :)

Answer (score 3):

As Minh Kieu recommended in the comments, I added this to the shell script of `wsdl2java`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Then I restarted Eclipse and now it worked.